# Accessing FTP files from Scala

Tags: scala, ftp

I can't seem to find a idiomatic way to access FTP files from a Scala library. 
Are there any mature libraries for this in Scala, or whould the prefered way be, to use the Java libraries for instance the Apache FTP client?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just use the java library...who in their right mind would reimplement this in scala?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a dedicated Scala library.
The only scala project managing FTP access is **[Scalanet](https://github.com/lundmelcher/scalanet)**, but:

- it hasn't been updated since 2009
- it simply encapsulates the `org.apache.commons.net.ftp` classes from the [Apache Commons Net™ library](http://commons.apache.org/net/) (as seen in the [FTP`.scala` class](https://github.com/lundmelcher/scalanet/blob/47478722bdc439071df502d13882981a20220db1/src/main/scala/net/ftp/FTP.scala))

Comment: The link doesn't work. Seems the library is not even available anymore.

Comment: @kfkhalili Thank you. This is not surprising for a 9 years old answer. While the library might not be accessible, forks of said library are still there. I have used one of those forks to restore the links.